# Change the look and Feel to Frame by an other one in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

hey guys i've two Frames one is the login Frame means it's the main frame and an other one it's my application i create a method to change the look&feel by radio button in the main of this frame but when i run my application it's doesn't work if i run it without the login frame it works goood i used this for the change :

```
public static void changeLaf(JFrame frame) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException  | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
    }
```

and

```
public static void changeLaf(JFrame frame, String laf) {
           if (laf.equals("nimbus")) {
            try {
                UIManager
                        .setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }
             if (laf.equals("dark")) {
            try {
                UIManager  
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }
              if (laf.equals("system")) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                        .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }

             if (laf.equals("sky")) {
            try {
                UIManager  
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.AeroLookAndFeel");


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }
             if (laf.equals("Orange")) {
            try {
                UIManager  
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.graphite.GraphiteLookAndFeel");


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }
             if (laf.equals("Dark2")) {
            try {
                UIManager  
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }
              if (laf.equals("XP")) {
            try {
                UIManager  
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.luna.LunaLookAndFeel");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }
             if (laf.equals("Texture")) {
            try {
                UIManager  
                        .setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            }
        }

        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
    }
```

Comment: How about, you print the stack trace of these exceptions, instead of ignoring them. Never just ignore exceptions, they are the seeds of bugs.

Comment: it was just an Automaticly try catch block added by NetBeans

Comment: i did there's no error and no action